# Object class isn't painting to screen

Tags: java, swing, paint

I am currently working on a small coding project and I've run into an issue. I've looked over my past work and I can't seem to figure out why this program wont call the paint method. Currently I'm just trying to draw a circle to the frame.

The following creates the window and the object class for the simple circle I'm trying to draw.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int WIDTH = 700, HEIGHT = 900;

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Physics Demo");
    JPanel content = new JPanel();

    content.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));

    Character ball = new Character(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    Timer changeFrame = new Timer (100, ball);

    frameSetup(frame, content, WIDTH, HEIGHT, ball, changeFrame);

}

public static void frameSetup(JFrame frame, JPanel content, int WIDTH, int HEIGHT, Character ball, Timer changeFrame){

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setContentPane(content);

    content.add(ball);

    frame.addKeyListener(ball);

    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));

    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    frame.setVisible(true);
    changeFrame.start();

}
```

}

The class below is the object class, when I run the program I get a response from the console. Character triggers once (as it should) and the actionPreformed method runs on loop with the timer. For some reason it doesn't run the paint class.

```
public class Character extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener{
/* Identify the Objects values and physics,
 * Characters weight, size and properties are below.
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

final int characterRadius = 30;

final double characterWeight = 0.5;

int characterY, characterX;

boolean bouncy;

public Character(int WIDTH, int HEIGHT){

    System.out.println("Character called upon... " + WIDTH);

}

public void characterObject(Graphics g, int WIDTH, int HEIGHT){

    super.paint(g);

    System.out.println("characterObject graphics called upon... " + WIDTH);

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillOval(350, 450, characterRadius, characterRadius);

}

/*
 * Ball does not have any player interactions
 */

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent buttonPressed) {


}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {


}

//******************************************

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

    System.out.println("actionPreformed called upon...");

    repaint();

}
```

}

I've been doing trial and error for a while now and I can't seem to figure it out so I'm using this as a last resort.

I can supply more information if needed.

Comment: Why are you calling `super.paint` from `characterObject`? This is not how custom painting works. You don't control the painting process, the API does

Answer (score 3):

Why are you calling `super.paint` from `characterObject`? This is not how custom painting works. You don't control the painting process, the API does

You need to override one of the methods called when the API want's the component to be repainted.  As a general recommendation, this would the `paintComponent` method, for example

```
public class Character extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    /* Identify the Objects values and physics,
     * Characters weight, size and properties are below.
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    final int characterRadius = 30;

    final double characterWeight = 0.5;

    int characterY, characterX;

    boolean bouncy;

    public Character(int WIDTH, int HEIGHT) {

        System.out.println("Character called upon... " + WIDTH);

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        System.out.println("characterObject graphics called upon... " + WIDTH);

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval(350, 450, characterRadius, characterRadius);

    }

    /*
     * Ball does not have any player interactions
     */
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent buttonPressed) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {

    }

    //******************************************
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        System.out.println("actionPreformed called upon...");

        repaint();

    }
}
```

I would recommend having a read of [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details about how painting actually works in Swing.

I'd also recommend having a look at [How to use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) as a replacement for `KeyListener`, which will address you next obvious issue

You may also want to have a read of [Java Coding Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for other people to read your code and easier for you to read others.

You're passing the `width` and `height` to the `Character` constructor, but are ignoring them, I'd suggest you're going to need to assign those values to instance fields and use them within the `paintComponent` method

Answer (score 0):

You should not call paint directly. It is called from the framework whenever repaint is needed. To force repaint just call 'repaint()'.

In case you call it from a timer you might need to put the call into the EDT that means the EventDispatchThread:

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    ball.repaint();
  }
});
```

Oh and you really should override the paint method:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
  super.paint(g);
  g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
  g.fillOval(350, 450, characterRadius, characterRadius);
}
```

Comment: Since `javax.Swing.Timer` calls the registered `ActionListener` on the EDT and the `Ball` class implements the `ActionListener` interface and calls `repaint` from within it - it would be reasonable to assume that this is not the problem. We could also discuss because of the way the `RepaintManager` works, `repaint` is one of the few methods which is generally thread safe